# Differencies between git add and git stage command

Tags: git

What is the difference between `git add filename` and `git stage filename`? Because when I tried them both it looks that they do the same thing.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

As [the documentation says](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stage.html), `git stage` is just a synonym for `git add`, so there is no difference in usage.

Answer (score 31):

To add to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175877/6309), that synonym was introduced in [commit 11920d2 (git 1.6.1-rc2, Dec. 2008](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11920d28da1ac1b65eb4041c1b7355924e5d1366))

> ### Add a built-in alias for '`stage`' to the '`add`' command
>
> This comes from conversation at the GitTogether where we thought it would
>   be helpful to be able to teach people to 'stage' files because it tends
>   to cause confusion when told that they have to keep 'add'ing them.
>
> This continues the movement to start referring to the index as a staging area (eg: the `--staged` alias to '`git diff`'). Also adds a doc file for '`git stage`' that basically points to the docs for '`git add`'.

---

That latter influenced the `git status` output, in [commit 8009d83, git 1.7.4-rc0, Nov 2010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8009d83c7e7af0a298ef858609a8201d01086396).
The message "`Changed but not updated`" was rewritten into "`Changes not staged for commit`"

> ### Better "`Changed but not updated`" message in `git status`
>
> Older Gits talked about "updating" a file to add its content to the index, but this terminology is confusing for new users.
>   "`to stage`" is far more intuitive and already used in e.g. the "`git stage`" command name.